# WordPress - disable URL with ID (SEO)

Tags: wordpress, url, seo, permalinks

I have installed WordPress and created permalinks for every page.

However, there is still a version available with example.com/?p=123 which represents the ID in the database.

Is it possible to disable these links so only my permalink is available?

I have seen that Google has indexed my permalinks and links with the ID - do I have to create a 301 redirect for every ID link to the permalink version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have enabled permalinks in the [**settings**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Choosing_your_permalink_structure), then WordPress will automatically redirect those URLs for you via its built in canonical API:

`example.com/?p=123 => example.com/pretty-url` (happens automatically)

Manually adding redirects will result in a redirect loop for those pages.

Google will eventually re-index your pages with the [**pretty permalinks**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Introduction_to_Blogging#Pretty_Permalinks) you have set up.

It might help to ask Google to [**re-crawl**](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6066468?hl=en) the website via Google's Search Console.

Answer (score 0):

If you have enabled permalinks in the settings, then WordPress will automatically redirect those URLs for you via its built in canonical API:

example.com/?p=123 => example.com/pretty-url (happens automatically)

Manually adding redirects will result in a redirect loop for those pages.

Google will eventually re-index your pages with the pretty permalinks you have set up.

It might help to ask Google to re-crawl the website via Google's Search Console.